# Insertar múltiples valores dentro de una misma posición en un array

Tags: javascript

quería saber si es posible poder insertar múltiples datos dentro de una posición de un array usando JavaScript, me refiero así:

arr[0] = [1,2,3],
arr[1] = [4,5,6]

Y después acceder a uno de esos datos, por ejemplo si quiero recuperar el dato "2" de arr[0], se puede?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Es posible, estaríamos hablando de una matriz es decir un arreglo de arreglos. Que requieres hacer y así mismo se te puede orientar mejor en esa parte

Comment: Es complicado explicar lo que estoy haciendo, ya intenté explicarlo en alguna pregunta pasada y no logro explicarlo bien, solo pregunto por algunas maneras para poder resolver mi problema ya que soy nuevo con el lenguaje. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Has buscado e investigado la respuesta a esa pregunta? Si es que sí, ¿que has encontrado? Lo digo porque no pones un [example] y eso lo puedes encontrar en [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=array+multidimensional+javascript) facilmente.

Comment: entonces averigua como crear matrices en javascript, eso sería lo que estás intentando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En respuesta a tu pregunta.

Lo que expones son matrices o arreglos pero en javascript se les dice que son matrices multidimencionales.

Esto debido a que el arreglo contiene otros arreglos y esos ya contienen lo que deseas, en este caso números.

Te dejo una página de referencia: [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)

En resumidas cuentas lo que expones sería un arreglo la cual en el javascript tradicional se declara de la siguiente manera inicializandolo como un arreglo vacío:

```
// Este es un arreglo de tipo any, es decir de cualquier tipo
var arreglo = [];
```

Es decir, puedes almacenar cualquier cosa en dicho arreglo, de la siguiente manera:

```
// Almacenamos un boleano
arreglo.push(true);

// Almacenamos un texto
arreglo.push('Hola Bilbit');

// Almacenamos un arreglo.
// este arreglo tiene las mismas caracteristicas que ya mencionamos
arreglo.push([true, 2, 'asdf', []]);
```

Ahora, para lo que requieres, sería un arreglo que almacene otro arreglo y este que se almacena contiene números.

El problema es que si inicializamos la variable como mostré en un comienzo, No es posible agregar algún dato en una posición determinada, es decir:

```
var arreglo = [];
arreglo[0] = [123];
```

Este arreglo nos va a presentar problemas, ya que no tiene ninguna posición inicializada, si vas a tener un arreglo al cual vas a aexarle información en una posición específica, debes crear el arreglo donde alcance esa posición en el momento de inicializarlo con un valor por defecto, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
// Creamos el arreglo y le inicializamos 3 posiciones.
var arreglo = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

De esta manera, si deseamos anexarle información mediante las posiciones se puede hacer sin problemas, ejemplo:

```
var arreglo = [undefined];
arreglo[0] = [123];
```

De esta manera si deseas usar dicha información posteriormente va a funcionar.

Dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
// Inicializamos la variable arreglo
var arreglo = [undefined];

// Anexamos información a la primer posicion inicializada como undefined
arreglo[0] = [123];

// Imprimimos la información almacenada
console.log('primer console', arreglo);

// Agregamos una nueva posición
arreglo.push([456]);

// Imprimimos las 2 posiciones
console.log('segundo console', arreglo);

// Modificamos la posicion 2
arreglo[1] = [789];
console.log('tercer console', arreglo);
```

Comment: Esto realmente me ayudo mucho!! muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar varios valores dentro de una posición con Javascript es sencillo

```
//Creas tu array

var data=[];

//Le das valor a las posiciones

data.push({"Valor1":1,"Valor2":2});
data.push({"Valor1":3,"Valor2":4});
console.log(data[0]["Valor1"]); //1
console.log(data[0]["Valor2"]); //2
```

> Esto te dará el valor de 1

Te dejo para que pruebes

```js
//Creas tu array
var data=[];

//Le das valor a las posiciones
data.push({"Valor1":1,"Valor2":2});
data.push({"Valor1":3,"Valor2":4});
console.log(data[0]["Valor1"]); //Valor de 1
console.log(data[0]); //Valor de data en la posición 0
```

Acá el link para que puedas probar y modificar

> https://jsfiddle.net/5ka1mv36/4/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!